# Holomorphic functions on unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f,g$ be holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}:=\lbrace z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\rbrace$, $f\neq0,g\neq0$, such that $$\frac{f^{\prime}}{f}(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{g^{\prime}}{g}(\frac{1}{n}) $$ for all natural $n\geq1$. Does it imply that $f=Cg$, where $C$ is some constant?

Let $A:=\lbrace\frac{1}{n}:n\geq1\rbrace$ and $h:=\frac{f^{\prime}}{f}-\frac{g^{\prime}}{g}$. Now, $h$ is holomprphic on $\mathbb{D}$ and disappears on a subset of $\mathbb{D}$ which has a limit point. Thus $h=0$, so $\frac{f^{\prime}}{f}=\frac{g^{\prime}}{g}$ on $\mathbb{D}$.

Could someone help with the next steps? Or maybe $f$ doesn't have to be in the form described above?

Comment: Notice that $f'/f \equiv \operatorname{d}\log f$. Moreover, if $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic then they are continuous and so when you apply a function to a sequence, the limit of the values if the value of the limit. (If $x_k \to \ell$ then $f(x_k) \to f(\ell)$.)

Answer (score 2):

Notice that your last statement is equivalent to ${f'g-g'f}=0$, since $f,g \neq 0$. Now there is no harm in dividing that expression by $g^2$. You get ${f'g-g'f}{g^2}=0$. So, $(f/g)'=0$ and so your result follows.

Comment: The "*it follows*" bit is what the OP was asking for help with. One needs to argue in terms of convergent sequences, limit points, and continuous functions. (We're not told that $f/f' \equiv g/g'$, just that they agree on a convergent sequence.)

Comment: @FlybyNight But it appears that the O.P figured out how $f/f'=g/g' $ on the entire disk from what the problem told. (See his last but third sentence).

I think what the OP needed was to see that $f/f'=g/g' $ is really the quotient rule in disguise.

The rest should not be too difficult. Perhaps I am wrong.
Since $f,g$ are holomorphic and neither is zero in our domain, $f/g$ is defined and holomorphic. Since it's derivative is zero, it is a constant.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ and $g$ are allowed to be $0$ somewhere (but not everywhere), the result is  still true.  Suppose $g(z) = z^k G(z)$ where $k$ is a nonnegative integer and $G$ is holomorphic on ${\mathbb D}$ with $G(0) \ne 0$.  Then $$\dfrac{g'(z)}{g(z)} = \dfrac{k}{z} + \dfrac{G'(z)}{G(z)} = \dfrac{k}{z} + O(1) \text{ as } z \to 0 $$
So from the sequence $(g'/g)(1/n)$ we can determine $k$.  Thus if $(g'/g)(1/n) = (f'/f)(1/n)$ for all $n$ we also have $f(z) = z^k F(z)$ (for the same $k$) where $F$ is 
holomorphic on ${\mathbb D}$ with $F(0) \ne 0$, and $F'/F = G'/G$.  Since you already 
proved the result for functions nonzero at $0$, it follows that $f/g = F/G$ is constant.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Since $$\frac{f'}{f}=\frac{g'}{g}$$ on $\Bbb D$, then $f'g-fg'=0$ on $\Bbb D$, and so $$\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)'=\frac{f'g-fg'}{g^2}=0$$ on $\Bbb D$. Can you get the rest of the way from there and see why $\frac{f}{g}$ is holomorphic on $\Bbb D$?

Comment: That's not the quotient rule for derivatives. Should be $g^2$ on the bottom.